# How to add/set validations (require, prestine etc) on custom angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created an angular directive as follows:

```
angular.module('SharedModule')
    .directive('multiSelect', ['$ionicModal', multiSelect]);


function multiSelect($ionicModal) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: [
            '<div ng-click="showItems($event)" class="item-icon-right item">',
            '{{text}}',
            '<i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-right"></i>',
            '</div>'
        ].join(""),
        scope: {
            'items': '=',
            'value': '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, $filter) {
            //validations
            //if (typeof attrs.required != "undefined"){
            //    // a value is required, hence invalidate this control.
            //
            //}

            //Some specific logic here. 

            scope.validate = function () {
                // validation that kicks in when user chooses to close the modal. 
            };

            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                scope.modal.remove();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

What this basically does is gives a user an option to select multiple contact types from a modal dialog used in an ionic app.

I use this directive in my html (inside a form) as follows:

```
<multi-select
    name="contactTypes"
    items="contact_types"
    text="Contact types"
    header-text="Choose contact types"
    allow-empty="false"
    ng-model="contact.contact_types"
    ></multi-select>
```

Question:
I am not sure how to set ng-pristine,ng-required ng-untouched classes if the user has not selected anything. 
Where would the code to manage custom validation go? What do i need to do so that i could use this directive as any other input control with ng-model?

Comment: See "Custom validation" at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to interact with `ng-model`, as described [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) (especially under "Custom Control Example"). To summarize:

1. Start by requiring the `ngModel`:

   ```
   function multiSelect($ionicModal) {
       return {
           ...
           require: 'ngModel',
           ...
       };
   }
   ```
2. In the `link` function get the `ngModel` and redefine `$isEmpty`. The default checks whether the value is `undefined`, `''`, `null` or `NaN`. You probably want to add the empty array to this check, e.g.:

   ```
   link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
       ...
       var originalIsEmpty = ngModel.$isEmpty;

       ngModel.$isEmpty = function(value) {
           return originalIsEmpty.call(ngModel, value) || value.length === 0;
       };
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Having done this, you only need to add `ng-required` to your directive:

   ```
   <multi-select ... ng-required="true"></multi-select>
   ```

   Angular will call your own implementation of `$isEmpty` and add the `ng-invalid-required` class to the `<multi-select>` element.

`$pristine` and `$untouched` *may* work out of the box. If not, you will have to add code that calls the appropriate methods of `ngModel`:

1. Whenever the user opens the dialog - the control is touched, do `ngModel.$setTouched()`.
2. Whenever the user presses "OK" in the dialog box *AND* actual changes are made - the control value has changed, it is no longer pristine, do `ngModel.$setDirty()`.

By the way, having access to `ngModel` in the `link` function makes the `scope: { 'value': '=ngModel' }` redundant.

Comment: For future references, use `ngModel.$setViewValue()` to set value instead of assigning it directly.